# Width <li> fit to content depending on height - IE/Chrome?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive

I am trying to set up a carousel and I have a small display problem in IE and Chrome (FF is OK).

```css
body,
html{height:100%;}

ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
  list-style: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline;
  height:20%;
  width:100%;}

li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:3px;
  height:inherit;
  background-color:red;}

li.last_item{margin-right:0;}

img{
  border: 0 none;
  display: block;
  filter: brightness(120%) saturate(130%) contrast(90%);
  vertical-align: middle;
  height:100%;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/404788P1010437s.jpg" alt="{{txt_video_title}}" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/404788P1010437s.jpg" alt="{{txt_video_title}}" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/404788P1010437s.jpg" alt="{{txt_video_title}}" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/404788P1010437s.jpg" alt="{{txt_video_title}}" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/404788P1010437s.jpg" alt="{{txt_video_title}}" />
  </li>
  <li class="last_item">
    <img src="http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/404788P1010437s.jpg" alt="{{txt_video_title}}" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my example, I simply put the basic structure without JavaScript to be clearer. Basically, my pictures are displayed one after the other and I want my list to take up 20% of window height.

When I resize the window height in FF there is no problem, `LI` fits well in height to 20% of the page and fits well in width to the image.

But in IE and Chrome, the ratio is not respected in width. I put a `background: red ;` on the `LI` to make it more obvious.

I do not wish to use Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest way to do this is by switching out `height: 20%;` with `height: 20vh`.

`vh` is a viewport unit, and is widely supported by modern browsers. You can read more about the viewport units here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I simply changed `height: 20%;` by `height: 20vh` but there is still the same problem.

So I changed all the units in my css, but nothing changes.